# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL ASP.NET mvc3

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Suppose I have following string:

var myString="`<ol>\r\n<li>Some text</li>\r\n</ol>`";

when I am trying to alert(myString) everything is ok but,

Suppose I have Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
   public string TestProperty{get;set;}
}
```

In controller  I am setting  `TestProperty=myString`
in view :

```
@model MyModel
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        alert('@Model.TestProperty')// here I am getting error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    })
</script>
```

I cant figure out what is the problem ,and how to fix it .
Thanks a  lot for your attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your generated javascript looks like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/MhtEL/

```
alert('<ol>
      <li>sometext</li>
      </ol>');
```

Which isn't valid javascript (string literals can't span multiple lines).

You could replace the newlines first:

```
alert('@Model.TestProperty.Replace("\r\n", "")')
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution ,this is working except  console.log('@Model.TestProperty'); ,this will throw same error.

Comment: Oh, duh. Not sure what I was thinking there.